# Checking if a String container any of a set of Symbols in Dart

Tags: dart

I would like to check if a string contains any of the following symbols ^ $ * . [ ] { } ( ) ? - " ! @ # % & / \ , > < ' : ; | _ ~ ` + =

I tried using the following

```
string.contains(RegExp(r'[^$*.[]{}()?-"!@#%&/\,><:;_~`+=]'))
```

But that does not seem to do anything. I am also not able to add the `'` symbol.

Questions:

1. How do I check if a string contains any one of a set of symbols?
2. How do I add the `'` symbol in my regex collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When writing such a `RegExp` pattern, you should escape the special symbols (if you want to search specifically by them).

Also, to add the `'` to the `RegExp`, there is no straightforward way, but you could use String concatenation to work around this.

This is what the final result could look like:

```
void main() {
  final regExp = RegExp(
    r'[\^$*.\[\]{}()?\-"!@#%&/\,><:;_~`+=' // <-- Notice the escaped symbols
    "'" // <-- ' is added to the expression
    ']'
  );
  
  final string1 = 'abc';
  final string2 = 'abc[';
  final string3 = "'";
  
  print(string1.contains(regExp)); // false
  print(string2.contains(regExp)); // true
  print(string3.contains(regExp)); // true
}
```

Comment: Actually, [`String.contains`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/String/contains.html) does search for a `Pattern`. You can use it with a `RegExp`.

Comment: Oh, right, never used it this way, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To ad both `'` an `"` to the same string literal, you can use a multiline (triple-quoted) string.

```dart
string.contains(RegExp(r'''[^$*.[\]{}()?\-"'!@#%&/\\,><:;_~`+=]'''))
```

You also need to escape characters which have meaning inside a RegExp character class (`]`, `-` and `\` in particular).

Another approach is to create a set of character codes, and check if the string's characters are in that set:

```dart
var chars = r'''^$*.[]{}()?-"'!@#%&/\,><:;_~`+=''';
var charSet = {...chars.codeUnits};
var containsSpecialChar = string.codeUnits.any(charSet.contains);
```